# XML Flash problem in Joomla

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, content-management-system, joomla

I've been creating a XML Flash Carousel for my website in AS2 in Flash. I've managed to get it working, the icons are images specified in the XML file, as well as links to click on each icon which lead to an external site.

My problem is, when I embed this same Flash file into Joomla, it doesn't display, it just leaves a space where that object should be (a space of 650 x 400 pixels). When I right click this space, you get the usual 'About Adobe Flash Player 10' message you get when you right click any Flash file.

This is obviously a XML problem rather than a Flash problem because the Flash is there but its not displaying anything because it can't read the file to get the icons to display them.

Is there anybody who can help with this? Is there a common thing with Joomla where you can't use XML with Flash or XML with Joomla at all?

Just for your reference, I've put the entire Carousel in the images/stories folder in my file structure.

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a crossdomain issue.
1. What is the URL in the browser to your site.
2. What it the URL that you have coded into your flash file to download the XML.

If they are not in the same domain you will get issues.
eg. 
You go www.mysite.com/filewithflash.html
flash file loads mysite2.com/xml.xml (note no www).
Or file is loading form a different domain.

Use [www.getcharles.com](http://www.getcharles.com) which is a java app, it will show you all the files that are being loaded and why the flash is not working (I assume its looking for the wrong file).

Comment: I've loaded all the files including the xml file into the same folder on the server. The Url for the particular page on my site is http://www.myramis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=54, the xml call is just: xml.load("icons.xml"); as it is in the same folder as the images and flash embedded references the .swf which is also in the same folder on the server. Is this the wrong way to do it though?

Comment: That all sounds right. Install www.getcharles.com its free. It will show you why files are not loading.  If they are loading then there is something wrong with your app.

Comment: hmm its finding the xml file but not the images now, its searching for http://www.myramis.com/icon5.jpg but i've specified in the xml file that its in images/stories/carousel/icon5.jpg..how would i modify this to find it as a url?

Comment: i've modified the xml file so that it reads the correct url for the image eg. <icon image ="images/stories/carousel/icon1.jpg but charles is still showing that the site is still trying to get www.myramis.com/icon1.jpg rather than www.myramis.com/images/stories/carousel/icon1.jpg...so now to get over this problem.

Comment: i've got it working now, really appreciate your help. I ended up putting the xml file in a different location from the images and the swf and it seemed to do the trick. Xml file is now in www.myramis.com/xml.xml

Comment: Awesome stuff.  That Charles app is made by a friend, its worth every cent, I have used it for the last 5 years for everything, makes web development so much easier. It can even decode json requests into nice tree structure and AMF.  Glad you sorted it.